# Generalize Numpy slicing Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing

I am not getting an idea how I can generalize the slicing of the numpy array. 
See the following slicing:

```
x_train = data[:train_set_size,:-1,4:-1]    
x_valid = data[train_set_size:train_set_size+valid_set_size,:-1,4:-1]
x_test = data[train_set_size+valid_set_size:,:-1,4:-1]

y_train = data[:train_set_size,-1,-2:]
y_valid = data[train_set_size:train_set_size+valid_set_size,-1,-2:]
y_test = data[train_set_size+valid_set_size:,-1,-2:]
```

As you can see `x` set is sliced as `:-1,4:-1` and `y` set as  `-1,-2:`. If I have to make changes then I need to change 3 times whereas if there a way to store the slicing in variable and just change variable and the changes are reflected.

for example: `xset_slice = ":-1,4:-1"` and `yset_slice = "-1,-2:"`. Then just replacing in the place as:

```
x_train = data[:train_set_size,xset_slice ]    
x_valid = data[train_set_size:train_set_size+valid_set_size,xset_slice ]
x_test = data[train_set_size+valid_set_size:,xset_slice ]
y_train = data[:train_set_size,-1,-2:]
y_valid = data[train_set_size:train_set_size+valid_set_size,yset_slice ]
y_test = data[train_set_size+valid_set_size:,yset_slice]
```

But this sort of statement gives error. Hence, please let me know is there any analogous methodology that can help me.

Comment: for a slicing of `[1:2]` you would save `x=1` and `y=2` and then do `[x:y]`. You cannot slice with strings.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I had similar idea. But there was a confusion. If I need to slice the last column, then i try `[-1]` or or `[-1:]`, so what value does `x` and `y` has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could construct the indices from `slice` objects and tuples:

```
slice1 = slice(-1)
slice2 = slice(4,-1)
slice3 = slice(-2,None)

x_train = data[:train_set_size,slice1, slice2]    
x_valid = data[train_set_size:train_set_size+valid_set_size, slice1, slice2]
x_test = data[train_set_size+valid_set_size:, slice1, slice2]
```

Make a composite tuple by joining several tuples:

```
tup1 = (slice1, slice2)
# or with np.s_[:-1, 4:-1]
x_train = data[(slice(train_set_size),+tup1]    
...
```

Comment: This is interesting @hpaulj. I will try and implement your answer. Thank you for answering and keep answering.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test 
    = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

 X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val 
    = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```

Comment: This might be helpful but the above answer of @hpaulj is quite impressive for my scenario. Thank you for your answer . I will upvote.